# How to access variables in a function, where are they stored in memory

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, memory, global

Hey where doe Python store variables in a function and how do i access them
Lets say i have the following code:

```py
import ctypes
def reveal():
     me = "where"
     print(id(me))
reveal() # memory_address
reveal() # same memory_address
ctypes.c_long.from_address(memory_address).value #1
```

from this i conclude that the variable has to be stored somewhere
i cant find it in `globals()` and it is not in the function `__dict__`
i dont know where to look for it or is it not accessible from outside of the function scope

Comment: When the function was compiled, a string object was created for the `"where"` literal, and stored in the function's list of constant values - `reveal.__code__.co_consts`.  This is not a documented feature of Python (so any code that relies on it is *utterly broken*), and the position of any given constant in that list doesn't seem to be predictable.

Answer (score 0):

No way. This variable is declared in the function's local scope and cannot be accessed outside of this function.

Comment: Depend on what they mean. Maybe they mean the string object...

Comment: i don't understand you. How can i get access for this variable? Give me example, please, it is very interesting for me

Comment: Now you're as unclear as the OP. What do you mean with "variable"?

Comment: in this case, it is `me`.

Comment: [If you mean the string object](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PyU1TaEotSw1MUdD04pLAQRyUxVsFZTKM1KLUpW4uAqKMvNKNCBK9OLjk/NTUuPj9ZLzgay84pJizf//AQ) (which is a **constant**).

Comment: but how do we determine exactly which value refers to a particular variable?

Comment: You're not getting any clearer...

Comment: @KellyBundy I think he is aksi how we can determine which value of the tuple refers to which "variable"/constant inside the function

Comment: @KellyBundy, I'm sorry I couldn't explain, but Alex did.