# Is it possible to access objects from a method which have just raised an exception?

Tags: python, exception

E.g. this code:

```
def foo():
    x = 5
    raise

def bar():
    try:
        foo()
    except:
        # access x here
```

is it possible to access x somehow?
Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72924212/how-to-access-variables-in-a-function-where-are-they-stored-in-memory/72924418#72924418)

Comment: @QwertYou not sure how this is a duplicate of the question you've linked to.

Comment: `x` is a name which only exists in the scope of `foo`

Comment: @PeterWood Yes, but in the case of an exception, it (or rather, the traceback referenced by the exception) carries a reference to that scope with it.

Comment: @chepner exactly, this is what I'm looking to investigate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on your use case, the more sensible approach would be to create a custom exception and give it the data:

```py
class MyException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, x, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.x = x

def foo():
    x = 5
    raise MyException(x)

def bar():
    try:
        foo()
    except MyException as e:
        print(e.x)
```

If you really need to be able to access all local variables, you can traverse the [traceback](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#traceback-objects) of the exception to retrieve the locals of each [stack frame](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#frame-objects). Here is a simple example that would work for your specific example:

```py
def bar():
    try:
        foo()
    except Exception as e:  # BaseException if you want to catch *everything*
        frame = e.__traceback__.tb_next.tb_frame
        print(frame.f_locals["x"])
```

Generally, the next frame will not necessarily be the one that raised the exception. You can traverse until you reach that frame like so:

```py
import traceback

def bar():
    try:
        foo()
    except Exception as e:
        # Get the last frame yielded, which will be where the exception was raised.
        *_, (frame, _) = traceback.walk_tb(e.__traceback__)
        print(frame.f_locals["x"])
```

Comment: Note that if you capture a reference to the exception, the traceback is also accessible via the exception's `__traceback__` attribute.

Comment: @chepner keeping reference of _frame_ object could lead to "cycles"? Shouldn't the _frame_ be explicitly deleted in this case?

Comment: I think that's the reason that `e` (the capture variable in the `except` clause) is implicitly deleted (as if with `del e`) after the `try` statement ends, to avoid such cycles. The exception object retains a reference to the traceback, but the frame will not contain a reference to the exception.

Comment: @chepner The [gc devguide](https://devguide.python.org/garbage_collector/#identifying-reference-cycles) also mentions it as the first example for cycles: "Exceptions contain traceback objects that contain a list of frames that contain the exception itself".

Answer (score -1):

Acces to the `code` object of the function via `__code__` attribute:

- `co_varnames`:
  tuple of names of arguments and local variables
- `co_consts`: tuple of constants used in the bytecode

This method could be useful to debug or to do dirty hack or to learn more about... python language!

It is not a universal solution but it depends on the *body* of the function under investigation. A more sophisticated tool that can used is [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) from the standard library.

```
def foo():
    x = 5
    raise

def bar():
    try:
        foo()
    except:
        local_var = {foo.__code__.co_varnames[0]: foo.__code__.co_consts[1]}
        print(local_var.items())

bar()
#dict_items([('x', 5)])
```

---

Here a way to access to the *traceback* of an exception. This method is **independent** on the type of exception:

```
import sys

def foo():
    x = 5
    raise

def bar():
    try:
        foo()
    except:
        tb = sys.exc_info()[-1]
        print(tb.tb_next.tb_frame.f_locals['x'])

bar()
#5
```

When an exception is met `sys.exc_info()` returns a triplet `(type, value, traceback)`, in this case would be:

`(<class 'RuntimeError'>, RuntimeError('No active exception to reraise'), <traceback object at 0x7f09c7d49e00>)`.

The traceback object is contained in the last entry,

- then use `tb_next` attribute to get the next inner traceback object
- `tb_frame` to get the frame object at this level and
- frame's `f_locals` attribute to get the local namespace of this frame (as dictionary).

Comment: Why are you even calling it? You're just reading/showing fixed data...

Comment: isn't it about getting `x`?

Comment: You're hardcoding an assumption that the variable you're interested in has value equal to `foo.__code__.co_consts[1]`. For most functions, that assumption will be false. (It might hold for this function, but if you were only interested in this function, you could just hardcode a `5`.)

Comment: @cards If they wanted what you're doing, why would they even be talking about "have just raised"?

Comment: @user2357112 yes it is sensible to the implementation of the function (I should have mentioned that) but still possible, it get `x` and `5`, **and** doesn't required new implementation

Comment: @Kelly Bundy I don't formalize too much on the English language... there is phantom  `method` in the title but only functions are shown

Comment: So if I do `x += 1` before the raising the exception, you report `6`?

Comment: after some additional work yes

Comment: What additional work?

Comment: inspecting further the content of `__code__` object

Comment: Looking forward to your update doing that.

Comment: `sum(...co_consts[1:3])`

Comment: Good one :-) ...

Comment: lol............

Comment: @user2357112 `co_consts[0]` points always to the function's doc-string (`None` if absent) so any values can be found in `[1:]`

Comment: And if the variable *isn't* just set to a constant value?