# Python ThreadPoolExecutor: How to evaluate what caused a timeout

Tags: python, exception, concurrency, python-multithreading

Given the following simple method that causes a `TimeoutError` at some point. How can I determine what were the conditions (e.g. arguments or something else) that caused the timeout?

```
In [82]: def f(i):
    ...:     print(i)
    ...:     if i == 2: time.sleep(1)
    ...:     return "done"
    ...:

In [83]: with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as ex:
    ...:     res = ex.map(f, range(10), timeout=0.001)
    ...:     try:
    ...:         for r in res:
    ...:             print(f"{r=}")
    ...:     except Exception as e:
    ...:         print(f"{e=}")
    ...:
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
8
7
r='done'
9
r='done'
e=TimeoutError()
```

Exception handling for `TimeoutError` in `f` does not work as the `TimeoutError` is raised when iterating through the result set.

```
In [84]: with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as ex:
    ...:     res = ex.map(f, range(10), timeout=0.001)
    ...:     for r in res:
    ...:         print(f"{r=}")
    ...:
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
r='done'
r='done'
8
9
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TimeoutError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [84], line 3
      1 with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as ex:
      2     res = ex.map(f, range(10), timeout=0.001)
----> 3     for r in res:
      4         print(f"{r=}")

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py:621, in Executor.map.<locals>.result_iterator()
    619             yield fs.pop().result()
    620         else:
--> 621             yield fs.pop().result(end_time - time.monotonic())
    622 finally:
    623     for future in fs:

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py:446, in Future.result(self, timeout)
    444             return self.__get_result()
    445         else:
--> 446             raise TimeoutError()
    447 finally:
    448     # Break a reference cycle with the exception in self._exception
    449     self = None

TimeoutError:
```

Comment: For a _traceback_ debugging approach, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72924612/is-it-possible-to-access-objects-from-a-method-which-have-just-raised-an-excepti/72924767#72924767)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception itself does not carry any relevant information. However, as the documentation says:

> The returned iterator raises a `concurrent.futures.TimeoutError` if `__next__()` is called and the result isn’t available after timeout seconds from the original call to `Executor.map()`

So the exception is always associated with the next element you tried to retrieve. If you keep track of the arguments, you can tell which one caused the issue.

```py
import time
from concurrent import futures


def f(i):
    time.sleep(i)
    return i


def run_checked(fun, args):
    args = list(args)
    idx = -1
    with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as tp:
        try:
            for idx, result in enumerate(tp.map(fun, args, timeout=4)):
                print(result)
        except futures.TimeoutError:
            print("Timeout on arguments '%s'" % args[idx + 1])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_checked(f, range(10))
```

Comment: spent 30 mins trying to figure out why it was out by 1, then saw `args[idx + 1]` :facepalm:

Comment: @aydow Heh, yeah, took me a minute to figure out this was the easiest way. My first instinct was to ```zip``` args and results, maybe after running args through ```itertools.tee``` so that it doesn't need to be a list. But that doesn't work well for the same reason